# How to hide few product page until the User Login in Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

I want to hide few products from Unregistered/non-login users. I have the following code. The code hide the whole category, but I want to hide a few products. If a user has the link to the product and tries to open a page, an error message should display.

```
function my_product_query( $q ) {
 
    // Not logged in
    if ( !$is_logged_in ) {
        $q->set( 'tax_query',
            array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $cat, // your category slug
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'my_product_query', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can add the custom field to all the products to find out whether the product is for logged-in users or non-logged-in users. Then, you can use below code for redirect non logged-in users.

```
add_action('template_redirect','custom_single_product_redirect');
function custom_single_product_redirect(){
    if (class_exists('WooCommerce')){
        if(is_product()){
            $is_loggedin = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'your_meta_field_key'); //get product meta key value, assuming boolean
            if($is_loggedin == 1 && !is_user_logged_in()){ //if user is not logged in and meta key is set to only for logged in users
                wp_redirect(home_url('/shop/'));
                exit();
            }
            
        }
    } 
    return;
}
```

Comment: What shall be changed in the code. I want to display only visible category to logout users, and login users can see each and every category.

Comment: The above will restrict user to access particular product. If you want, you can use the same custom field to Category and same condition for the category page.

Comment: I pasted the same code (did not make any changes in code), but the code is not working. Login and logout users can access the shop, category & product page.

Comment: The above is only for the product detail page. Also, have you added the meta field for the product (to check if the product is for logged-in users or non-logged in users)?

Comment: meta field for the product? Do you mean custom fields on the product page?

Comment: Yes, custom field on the product which will help to find whether product is available for logged in users or not.